# Picasa would not log into my account

Tags: 11.10, wine, internet, networking, google-picasa

I have installed Wine on 11.10, but for some reason Picasa does not detect the internet connection, which exist system wide, except for Picasa

Any suggestions?

Hi, I have reinstalled picasa 3.0 for linux after having replaced ubuntu 11.04 by 11.10. But this time I can log in web album/google account using any browser but cannot log in my picasa web album through picasa. Every time I try, it says authentication failure. I dont understand where the problem is. Could any one help?

Comment: could you provide more detail please, how do you know the internet does not work in wine? What type of internet are you using, wireless lan etc? Does internet explorer not connect to any pages?

Comment: That was a wrong assumption. I have installed Firefox using WineTricks, and it seems to working properly. However, Picasa would not login to my account. I get an error that Internet connection is not present. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Google provides official Picasa binaries for Linux: http://picasa.google.com/linux/. No need to use wine.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I find how to work this out.

If you've not already done so then install Wine. Now all you have to do is copying the wininet.dll.so file from /usr/lib/wine/ to /opt/google/picasa/3.0/wine/lib/wine/ overwriting the one that's there. Picasa should now work!

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=223743&highlight=picasa

Answer (score 2):

This guide work for me - [Install Picasa 3.9 In Linux And Fix Google Sign In Issue [Wine]](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-picasa-39-in-linux-and-fix.html) and also check this to integrate with gnome - [Picasa integrate with GNOME](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-install-picasa-36-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Shotwell, to post Photos in Picasa, It works perfectly.

This version of Picasa doesn't work because it uses libraries and other processes that only Windows uses. Just in case, Picasa for linux is outdated, they don't have a new version yet!

Answer (score -1):

It works!!! Before copying, need to obtain the root permission: run in Terminal: ”gksudo nautilus” (for ubuntu users).
Thanks a lot and sorry for poor english.